# New in Blender (coming from Modo)

Tags: modeling, add-on

I am trying to give it a try to Blender. After the 2.8 update I got totally in (visually) at least.

I am trying to explore the UI and I find a few differences that I am trying to understand. This is not a critic it is just doubts that I am trying to solve.

1. In Modo when I move a vertex or any other element of the geometry the "coordinates" are 0 from the beginning. For ex. If I grab an upper vertex of a cube and I click the move tool any units input will be 0+ X . 
   In blender the vertex of a cube has already the position in the space embedded, making my decitions little bit more complex. If I want to make a change in a vertex that vertex of the cube will not be 0, but 2m for example. Therefore If I want to move it 2mm ...I need to put 2002.

Is it possible to use it as in Modo ?

2. Is the boolean tool add-on working in 2.8 ?
3. Is there any shortcut to see my mesh subdivided view ? I mean in Modo when you press TAB it will swap to the subd version of that mesh. In Blender I need to open a modifier and activate it each time. I would like to have a short cut that that allows me to toggle the view of the subd vs regular mesh.
4. I am still not getting use to move the geometry parts with the shortcuts...I am coming from the product design field and I feel more comfortable moving things with a gizmo. Any option to have it always active when I press G ?
5. Is this the right forum to ask? There are several options in the official web. My apologies if this is not the right one.

Thanks so much for helping.

Comment: Please keep only one question per post, ask as many as necessary

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to blender.stackexchange. Please only post one question per post, you can post as many new questions as you want!

1. If you have the 3DView Transform Panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) open, it will show you the coordinates of a vertex. You can use an arithmethic operation if you want to offset a value. E.g. if the vertex is at (1, 2, 3) and you want to move it `4.5` units along Y, then you can simply double click into the Y field of the vertex transform. It will now read `2m` followed by the cursor. Typing `+4.5` and pressing <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> will shift it to `6.5` as expected.
   [image]
   You can also use the operation properties which appears in the box after completing an operation. Press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> and confirm with <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to move the vertex along Y. The operation dialog will show

```
Move X       0m
     Y       0.12345m
     Z       0m
```

Now you can change the the relative value, by clicking on the individual field, entering it and confirming with <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> or <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>.
[image]

2. The BoolTools Addon is not yet updated for 2.8. (25.12.19)
3. In Object Mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> if you're in edit mode): Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Number</kbd> to change the view level of the subdivision surface modifier. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> will be level one while <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> will show no subdivision at all, etc...
   [image: subsurf]
4. The gizmo is enabled with the buttons on the left hand side <kbd>T</kbd> or with <kbd>Space</kbd> > <kbd>G</kbd>/<kbd>R</kbd>/<kbd>S</kbd>/<kbd>3</kbd>
5. Questions 1 - 4 are almost right for this forum, view the [asking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/asking) section for more info. They should however be split into several posts in the future. This question  may get closed for that reason. Question 5 however, does not have anything to do with the usage of Blender, but with the  usage of this forum. It belongs to [meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I really appreciate your fast answer. Unfortunately It is not behaving as you explain :(

Comment: Sorry I am trying, but when I press "enter" the comment got sent ...

I can clarify of course:

1. If I make a cube. I pick a vertex and press -10 mm it does not subtract -10 in that axis. Not sure why.  It might be helpful If I could record a video from Modo. 

2. Nothing to add :) I guess I will wait

3. I managed to do it. The issue is that I am still not understanding the "object" mode function. I would like to toggle between my subd and mesh and e able to manipulate it. The operation now shows me the subd facetated without edges and I would like to see it as in edit more.

Comment: My gizmo only works when I go and press the move button, but I would like to not need that step. I just want to move like "g"  but having a gizmo. I am so sorry for being annoying , It is just that I am trying to understand if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: @Bruno I added some images. I still don't understand the *move like "g" but having a gizmo* part.

Comment: I am exploring the videos . I will reply asap :) thanks

Comment: 1. The first gif I am not totally understanding what is happening. You are moving the vertex to a position of 1M in one axis...then you press 20 mm and returns...to be a square?  The second gif it is super clear, it Is just that I am trying to avoid to use the "+" in order to move a vertex 20 mm for example. I believe my confusion comes from the workflow of modo. Where every vertex has a 0 value and then if you apply 20mm will move 20 mm, while in Blender goes to the coordinate 20 in the space.

Comment: Which app you use to record your screen ? I would like to show you what I am use to in order to find out if I am able to do it in Blender .

Comment: ScreenToGif. The images got mixed up, but I'll leave them like this to avoid confusion. In the first gif I am simply typing: G X 1, to move 1 along X. After that I can still alter the one. Since I correct the value to 0.02m, the movement is minute, it looks *almost* like a cube.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps a little bit.

in Blender 2.80 if you right click on the tools you could either add it to Quick Favorites (Q) or assign a Shortcut.

[image]

[image]

Good Luck